# Extract base URl from a string in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am currently working on a project with .NET 1.1 framework and I am stuck at this point. I have a string like "http://www.example.com/mypage/default.aspx" or it might be "http://www.example.edu/mypage/default.aspx" or "http://www.example.eu/mypage/default.aspx". How can I extract the base URl from this kind of a string.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a regular expression

Comment: Why so many variants of "use the Uri class"?  If someone already answered, better to suggest any improvements to their answer than create a dozen near-duplicates.

Comment: @EricJ. - this is how Ethernet works - anyone posts at the same time, than collision resolution takes place - only couple good ones survive :)

Comment: I'm sure you can find what you are looking for on the [Uri Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_properties.aspx) page

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov was more of a case of a lazy rubbish question deserving and begetting a lazy rubbish answer. I'll remove it though because it so offendeth thee... or I could have gone with the smiley face

Comment: @spender your's isn't a word

Comment: mysite.com is blacklisted, so I've edited everything to use example.com & similar

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use [URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.uri) class to get the host name.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/mypage/default.aspx");    
var host = uri.Host;
```

**Edit** You can use [uri.Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.uri.scheme) and [uri.Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.uri.port) to get the .Scheme e.g. (http, ftp) and .Port to get the port number like (8080)

```
string host = uri.Host;
string scheme = uri.Scheme;
int port = uri.Port;
```

You can use [Uri.GetLeftPart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.uri.getleftpart) to get the base URL.

> The [GetLeftPart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.uri.getleftpart) method returns a string containing the leftmost
>   portion of the URI string, ending with the portion specified by part.

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/mypage/default.aspx");    
var baseUri = uri.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Authority);
```

The following examples show a URI and the results of calling GetLeftPart with Scheme, Authority, Path, or Query, [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.uri.getleftpart).
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. It helped.

Thank you all for the responses as well.

Comment: @HRK: I don't understand how a request for a "base URI" is satisfied by an answer that provides the host. It's not what you asked.

Comment: +1 to this... @spender (+1 too) - since there is no really strict definition what "base URI" is it is very hard to guess what original poster needed... :)

Comment: this gives `www.example.com` (not including any port or protocol)

Answer (score 88):

**Short Answer**

```
myUri.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Authority)
```

**Long Answer**
Assuming "Base URI" means something like `http://www.example.com`, you can get the base uri like this:

```
var myUri= new Uri("http://www.example.com/mypage/default.aspx");    
var baseUri = myUri.GetLeftPart(System.UriPartial.Authority)
```

This gives: `http://www.example.com`

Note: `uri.Host` gives: `www.example.com` (not including port or scheme)

Answer (score 5):

```
var builder = new UriBuilder("http://www.example.com/mypage/default.aspx");
builder.Path = String.Empty;
var baseUri = builder.Uri;
var baseUrl = baseUri.ToString();
// http://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create an extension to the Uri class.  In my opinion things that should be there from the start.   It will make your life easier.

```
public static class UriExtensions
 {                   
    public static Uri AttachParameters(this Uri uri, 
                                       NameValueCollection parameters)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string str = "?";
        for (int index = 0; index < parameters.Count; ++index)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(str + 
                System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(parameters.AllKeys[index]) +
                 "=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(parameters[index]));
            str = "&";
        }
        return new Uri(uri + stringBuilder.ToString());
    }

    public static string GetBaseUrl(this Uri uri) {
        string baseUrl = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host;
        return baseUrl;
    }

    public static string GetBaseUrl_Path(this Uri uri) {
        string baseUrl = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host + uri.AbsolutePath;
        return baseUrl;
    }
 }
```

Usage:

```
//url -  https://example.com/api/rest/example?firstname=Linus&lastname=Trovalds
Uri myUri = new Uri("https://example.com/api/rest/example").AttachParameters(
            new NameValueCollection
            {
                {"firstname","Linus"},
                {"lastname","Trovalds"}
            }
          );
// https://example.com
string baseUrl = myUri.GetBaseUrl();
// https://example.com/api/rest/example
string baseUrlandPath = myUri.GetBaseUrl_Path();
```

Comment: You need to also append the port if the URI is not using the default one, this a potential bug

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all 3 of them in a list here is something you could also start with
there are so many options you can do once you get the `Host Name` also if you are wanting everything past the `.com` use the `AbsolutePath` method

```
var uriList = new List<string>()
            {
                "http://www.mysite.com/mypage/default.aspx",
                "http://www.mysite.edu/mypage/default.aspx",
                "http://www.mysite.eu/mypage/default.aspx"
            };
        var holdList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var uriName in uriList)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(uriName);
            holdList.Add(uri.Host);
        }
```